# How to clean obfuscated code from fake if statements?

Tags: deobfuscation, javascript

I am trying to deobfuscate javascript code. Firstly I extracted strings from big array. Then I saw many parts like this
[image]

There is only one line of code which makes sense. Is there any Node.js cleaner package exists?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution.
[Gist with Node.js code.](https://gist.github.com/vladgovor77771/eb98fc8a66da1aa61dea1544b0ea1e55)

Comment: Could you describe the approach and maybe quote some relevant parts in the answer?